# How to divide the table layout into equal parts vertically?

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout, android-tablelayout

I am new in android and had a query. 
I am creating a layout with table in it. I have linear layout as main layout and 3 child layout of which i have divided them using layout weight. Now my problem is that how can i divide the table layout in my linear layout in 6 equal parts (Its layout_weight is 0.70).

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_width="300dip"
    android:id="@+id/tablelayout01"
    android:layout_weight="0.70"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:weightSum="1">


    <TableRow 
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/tablerow01"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.10"
        android:gravity="center">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="Name"
            android:textColorHint="#333333"
            android:shadowRadius="2"  
            android:shadowColor="#000000"
            android:shadowDx="2"
            android:shadowDy="4">
            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

    </TableRow>

  <TableRow
       android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/tablerow02"
        android:layout_weight="0.10"
        android:gravity="center">

      <EditText
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:hint="Email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:textColorHint="#333333">
            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>  
  </TableRow>

   <TableRow
       android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/tablerow03"
        android:layout_weight="0.10"
        android:gravity="center">

      <EditText
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:textColorHint="#333333">
            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>  
  </TableRow>

     <TableRow
       android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/tablerow04"
        android:layout_weight="0.10"
        android:gravity="center">

      <EditText
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:hint="Confirm Password"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:textColorHint="#333333">
            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>  
  </TableRow>

    <TableRow
       android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/tablerow05"
        android:layout_weight="0.15">

      <Button
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_signup"
            android:text="Create Account"
            android:textColor="#ffffff">

        </Button>  
  </TableRow>  

        <TableRow
       android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/tablerow06"
        android:layout_weight="0.15"
         android:background="@drawable/fb_button" >

        <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/fb_button"
    android:id="@+id/linearlayout02">


        <ImageView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/facebook_icon"/>

         <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="Sign Up with Facebook"
        android:id="@+id/btn_fb"
        android:background="@drawable/fb_button"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>   

         </LinearLayout>

  </TableRow>  




</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is 6 equal parts then the parent should be a `weightSum` of 6 and each child should have a `layout_weight` of 1.

The `layout_weight` is defined by the view objects direct parent. So you could have a `weightSum` of 6 on the `LinearLayout` then a `layout_weight` of 1 and a `weightSum` of 6 on your `TableLayout` and each `TablRow` would have a `layout_weight` of 1.

---

**Edit**

There has to be something in your code that is conflicting with the weight, I have changed my code below to show (3) three items in the `LinearLayout` and (6) six in the `TableLayout`, I have also included a screenshot of exactly what it gives me in the preview and on my device.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="3" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tablelayout01"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="6" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tablerow01"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Name" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tablerow02"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Email" >
            </EditText>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tablerow03"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Password"
                android:inputType="textPassword" >
            </EditText>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tablerow04"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Confirm Password" >
            </EditText>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tablerow05"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tablerow06"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Item 2" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Item 3" />

</LinearLayout>
```

---

[image]

Comment: I fixed my answer to better fit your needs after I had re-read your question. Let me know if that helps. Your `EditText` shouldn't be bigger then the attributes you have defined. Don't copy and paste my code, I removed a lot of your attributes to better show what I was changing.

Comment: Hi Asok i Tried what you have edited but it still gives me the same result. I need to have all the table rows close to each other. What you have said leaves a lot of space between 2 rows

Comment: I have edited my answer again, there has to be something in your code that is conflicting with the weight. Take a look at what I have above and what I get as a result and play with your code to determine what is causing the issue.